# Property 'queueSid' does not exist on type 'WorkerActionPayload'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, twilio

I am trying to get queueSid from task but it causes my app to break completely with a console error "The above error occurred in the ACW component:"

```
class ACW extends React.Component<AfterCallWorkOwnProps> {
  constructor(props: AfterCallWorkOwnProps) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render(): JSX.Element {
    const featureFlags = new Config(Manager).config().features;
    const workerAttributes = Manager.getInstance().workerClient.attributes;
    const { task, queuesList } = this.props;
    **const queueData = getQueueData(queuesList, task?.queueSid);**
    console.log("task", queueData)

    return (
      <Portal
        containerId="acw-wrapper-container"
        reduxKey="enableAutoDispositionForACW"
        reduxValue={true}
        key="ACW-Portal"
        config={{ loaded: true, enableAutoDispositionForACW: true } as ConfigState}
      >
        {task &&
          TaskHelper.isInWrapupMode(task as ITask) &&
          featureFlags.enableAfterCallWork && isBoolean(workerAttributes.enableAfterCallWork) && (
            <Container>
              {`You have `}
              <CountdownTimer
                workerAttributes={workerAttributes}
                reservationId={task.sid || ''}
              />
              {` seconds to wrap up`}
            </Container>
          )}
      </Portal>
    );
  }
}
```

The getQueueData function

```
export const getQueueData = (queuesList: QueuesList[], queueSid: string) => {
  const queue = queuesList.find((x) => x.queueData.sid === queueSid);

  return queue?.queueData.props;
};
```

the task is traced to

```
export interface WorkerActionPayload {
    **task?: ITask;**
    sid?: string;
}
```

which is traced to an ITask

```
export interface ITask {
    source: any;
    sourceObject: any;
    addOns: object;
    age: number;
    attributes: Record<string, any>;
    dateCreated: Date;
    dateUpdated: Date;
    priority: number;
    queueName: string;
    **queueSid: string;**
    reason: string;
    sid: string;
    status: TaskReservationStatus;
    taskSid: string;
    taskStatus: TaskTaskStatus;
    taskChannelSid: string;
    taskChannelUniqueName: string;
    timeout: number;
    workflowName: string;
    workflowSid: string;
    workerSid: string;
    incomingTransferObject: TaskTransfer;
    outgoingTransferObject: TaskTransfer;
    routingTarget: string;
    defaultFrom: string;
    channelType: string;
    conference: Conference;
    complete: () => Promise<any>;
    transfer: (to: string, options: any) => Promise<any>;
    hold: (holdMusicUrl?: string, holdMusicMethod?: string) => Promise<any>;
    unhold: () => Promise<any>;
    holdParticipant: (targetSid: string, holdMusicUrl?: string, holdMusicMethod?: string) => Promise<any>;
    unholdParticipant: (targetSid: string) => Promise<any>;
    cancelTransfer: () => Promise<any>;
    kick: (targetSid: string) => Promise<any>;
    setAttributes: (attributes: object) => Promise<any>;
    wrapUp: () => Promise<any>;
}
```

In the ITask the queueSid is in there but I get the error "Property 'queueSid' does not exist on type 'WorkerActionPayload'." when I hover over the red underlined queueSid in my VS Code. What is causing this? I also tried replacing task with (task as ITask) but same results

Answer (score 1):

Well I can't see what your props are, but my assumption is that the `task` variable is actually of type `WorkerActionPayload`, which would mean you would need to write `task?.task?.queueSid`. Obviously renaming the task variable would be a good idea, if this is indeed the case.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried that as well and when I hover over it, i get "Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Comment: ah yes, the `task?` allows it to be undefined, so change the type string in your getQueueData function to string | undefined and then check to make sure it exists in your getQueueData function.

Comment: Or if you're certain the task will always be available, then just remove the ?

Comment: Thanks the string error went away, but the apps still crashes.

Did you mean like this?

```export const getQueueData = (queuesList: QueuesList[], queueSid: string | undefined) => {
  const queue = queuesList.find((x) => x.queueData.sid === queueSid);

  return queue?.queueData.props;
};```

Am I looking for the queueSid or task in getQueueData?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: The app crashes and I get the error "The above error occurred in the ACW component:" It might be a redux issue because the the queueList in const queueData = getQueueData(queuesList, task?.queueSid) also returns undefined